# Best technique to create oldschool (fake 3D) racing game?

Tags: 3d, rendering, racing

What would be a good approach to develop the render system for an oldschool type racing game that uses a pseudo 3D scenery, like for example **Outrun** or **Lotus Esprit Turbo Challenge**? There's an endless scrolling road and scenery graphics are placed like billboard items, etc. I think you get the idea.

[image: Screenshot from Lotus: The Ultimate Challenge]

Are these developed in a similar way like [Mode7](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mode_7) or is there a different technique behind it? Does the technique has a specific name I could search for on the web? I need to develop something like that in Flash.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

There's an [excellent article](http://www.extentofthejam.com/pseudo/) out there that explains the 3D rendering of these games in detail. And you'll also find a complete [implementation in JavaScript here](http://codeincomplete.com/posts/2012/6/23/javascript_racer_v1_straight/).

The basic idea is as follows: You divide your screen into a number of strips and use perspective-projection to calculate the texture-coordinates (scaling and y position inside the road-texture) for each strip. Then you draw the portion of the texture into the strip, resulting in a road that vanishes in the distance.

Answer (score 1):

They generate pseudo 3D scenery by using [perspective](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perspective_%28visual%29). They have a vanishing point at the center of screen. You can calculate by using [perspective projection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3D_projection#Perspective_projection).

Comment: I think you meant "perspective", not "perception".