# Is a game like Subway Surfers suited for 2D or 3D?

Tags: 2d, 3d, game-design, mobile

I imaginated a mobile game and now I'm getting doubts as to whether its possible for my idea to be developed in 2D. Here's a crude illustration of the game scene:

[image: Game scene]

It's pretty much like Subway Surfers. The game objective is simply a kid going along the street and buying particular fruits/vegetables. Can the sprites be changed in perspective?

As a side note, there's a reason for my particular love towards 2D. That's because:

- I don't want to employ someone for 3D designing, I can manage 2D myself.
- I want to finish developing this game quickly.

Comment: You can design it however you like. If you want to make it 2D, make it 2D. There are advantages and disadvantages of 2D, same as for 3D. For example, personally, I would find it more difficult to make convincing art for a 2D version of this game. It's possible to develop it in 2D. See these related: http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/49626/best-technique-to-create-oldschool-fake-3d-racing-game http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/22953/how-would-i-implement-an-endless-road-the-player-runs-down http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/25602/road-parallax-background?lq=1

Comment: I think this is fundamentally a 3d game, with simple 2d art (for the stuff on the sides).

Comment: @srikanth: I removed the "which technology to use for my game" bits, as it's considered off topic, don't get offended! Check the [help] for more info.

Comment: @LaurentCouvidou: sorry i didnt know the rules :) now i need some help in choosing the right tools... can u help me with that.?

Comment: @srikanth Well not really, I don't know a lot about mobile games. You said you were familiar with cocos2d, maybe you should start with that and come back ask your questions if you hit any blocker? You're the one that knows what you want so it's yours to choose your technology, really.

Comment: @LaurentCouvidou you got me wrong man. my question was that whether the above said idea could be implemented in cocos2D-x (a little googling pointed me towards cocoseD-x) or is there a better option out there. my background is javascript man.. i know nothing bout programming. hence this question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Either one. Consider that even if the game world is in 3D, you can still use 2D for rendering. This is primarily a design decision. If you're more comfortable with 2D, then use 2D.

See these related questions about making a similar style of game:

[Best technique to create oldschool (fake 3D) racing game?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/49626/best-technique-to-create-oldschool-fake-3d-racing-game)

[How would I implement an endless road the player runs down?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/22953/how-would-i-implement-an-endless-road-the-player-runs-down)

[Road parallax background](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/25602/road-parallax-background?lq=1)

You'll see that some of them describe 2D methods and others describe 3D methods. You're the only one that knows exactly what your project requirements are. It's up to you to decide which one to use.

It appears to me that Subway Surfers is created in 3D. There will be some differences between 2D and 3D no doubt.

Pseudo 3D:

[image]

3D:

[image]